# Nontrivial example of $M$ such that $\text{Ass}(M)=\varnothing$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring, and $M$ an $R$-module. Is there a nontrivial example of such $M$ where the set of [associated primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_prime) $\text{Ass}(M)=\varnothing$?

Taking $M=0$ feels kind of cheap, since any annihilator of $x\in M$ is necessarily all of $R$, and hence not prime.

Is there a better example that is still relatively simple, preferably with some explanation about why $\text{Ass}(M)=\varnothing$?

Comment: Any example is going to be somewhat "complicated" because $R$ has to be non-Noetherian.  If $R$ is a Noetherian ring, and $M$ is a non-zero $R$-module, then there must be an associated prime ideal.  Proof sketch: Consider the set of annihilators of non-zero elements of $M$.  This is a non-empty set of ideals of $R$ and therefore has a maximal element, since $R$ is Noetherian.  Show that this maximal element is prime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $k$ be a field and $R=k[X_0,X_1,X_2,..]/ \langle X_0^2,X_1^2,X_2^2,...\rangle=k[x_0,x_1,x_2,..]$. Then $\operatorname{Ass}_R(R)=\emptyset$ .

**Edit: a detailed proof**
At Lando's request I'll give a complete proof of the above.

1) Let's show that the only prime ideal of $R$ is the obviously maximal ideal $\mathfrak m=\langle x_0,x_1,x_2,...\rangle$.
Indeed,  if $\mathfrak p \subset R$ is  prime then for all $i\geq 0$ we deduce from $0=x_i^2\in \mathfrak p$ that  $x_i\in \mathfrak p$, so that $\mathfrak m=\langle x_0,x_1,x_2,...\rangle \subset \mathfrak p$ and since $\mathfrak m$ is maximal we have $\mathfrak p=\mathfrak m$.

2) It remains to prove that $\mathfrak m$ is not an associated ideal and we will have the desired conclusion $\operatorname{Ass}(R)=\emptyset$ ($R$ is seen as a module over itself).
To say that  $\mathfrak m$ is associated means that there exists $0\neq P\in R$ with $\mathfrak m=\operatorname{Ann}(P)$.
Such a $P$ can 
be written as $P(x_0,...,x_N)$, i.e. can involve only finitely many $x_i$'s.
But then we see that it is not true that $\mathfrak m=\operatorname{Ann}(P)$, because $x_{N+1}\notin \operatorname{Ann}(P(x_0,...,x_N))$: any non-zero term $rx_{i_0}...x_{i_s} \neq 0\; (0\leq i_0\lt\cdots\lt i_s\leq N$ ) of  $P(x_0,...,x_N)$ will satisfy $rx_{i_0}...x_{i_s}\cdot x_{N+1} \neq 0$ and so $ P(x_0,...,x_N)\cdot x_{N+1}\neq 0 $.

Comment: Thanks Georges. Can you explain how you indeed know that $\text{Ass}_R(R)=\varnothing$?

Comment: @LandoKal: The first step is to determine the prime ideals of $R$.

Comment: @Ted Sure, but it's not clear to me what they are. The elements of $R$ are polynomials in $k$ equivalent if their difference is divisible by some $\sum_i k_ix_i^2$. But then what?

Comment: Dear Lando, I have added a little hint: the ring is local. I'll add more details tomorrow (it's 02 a.m. !)

Comment: Dear Georges, thanks! I would like to see the details tomorrow, but  do please take your time.

Comment: @LandoKal: Use the fact that if an element of a ring is nilpotent (some power equals 0), then it must lie in every prime ideal of the ring.

Comment: @Ted So I guess I can assume off the bat that the representatives have no monomials with a variable of power greater or equal to $2$.  If I square it, this kills off all monomials multiplied by themselves, but gives a new representative whose monomials are pairwise products of distinct monomials. I'm getting a bit lost seeing where to go.

Comment: Dear Lando, I've had breakfast and then supplied a detailed proof of my assertion. If something is still not clear, do not hesitate to ask: math.stackexchange wants 100 % satisfied customers...